# MySQL Count Two Groups from a Joined Table

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, left-join, multiple-tables

I have a table called Tickets with id, name.
and a table called Articles with id, ticket_id, and status.

I'm trying to display all Ticket names, along with a COUNT of Articles with that ticket_id, and also a COUNT of articles with that ticket_id and status = '1'

So far I've tried this with no success:

```
SELECT t.name, count(a.id), count(aa.id)
FROM tickets t
LEFT JOIN articles a ON t.id = a.ticket_id GROUP BY t.id
LEFT JOIN articles aa ON t.id = aa.ticket_id AND aa.status = '1' GROUP BY t.id
```

Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work ...

```
    SELECT t.name, 
           count(a.id), 
           SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      FROM tickets t
      LEFT JOIN articles a 
        ON t.id = a.ticket_id 
     GROUP BY t.id,
           t.name
```